# Django - JSON serializers.serialize not working

Tags: jquery, django, json

I have the following code in views.py and I want to get the entire list of persons in a sate.

```
def all_json_persons(request, state):
    print "current_state--" + str(state)
    current_state = State.objects.get(id=state)
    print "current_state--" + str(current_state)
    districts = District.objects.all().filter(state=state)
    print "districts--" + str(districts)
    personsList = []
    for current_district in districts:
       villages = Address.objects.all().filter(district=current_district) 
       for current_village in villages:
          persons = Person.objects.all().filter(address=current_village)
          print "persons--" + str(persons)
          personsList.append(persons)  
    print "personsList--" + str(personsList)
    json_persons = serializers.serialize("json", personsList)
    print "json_persons--" + json_persons
    return HttpResponse(json_persons, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

It returns the following result on the terminal:

```
current_state--2
current_state--Odisha
districts--[<District: Jagatsighpur>, <District: Koraput>]
persons--[<Person: Annnn Ppppp>, <Person: Rrrrr Jeeee>, <Person: Raaaaa Jennn>, <Person: Annnnn Saaaa>]
persons--[<Person: Laaaa Sikaka>, <Person: Lingram  Azzzzz>]
personsList--[[<Person: Annnn Ppppp>, <Person: Rrrrr Jeeee>, <Person: Raaaaa Jennn>, <Person: Annnnn Saaaa>], [<Person: Laaaa Sikaka>, <Person: Lingram  Azzzzz>]]
**[15/Dec/2012 21:05:42] "GET /state/2/all_json_persons/ HTTP/1.1" 500 75201**
```

I am not able to figure out why the below line of code is not working in the above situation:

```
json_persons = serializers.serialize("json", personsList)
```

However, if I replace personsList in the above line with persons. It works good. But I want the entire list of persons in a state. Please help.

Comment: You should read [following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's serializers are for serializing *querysets*. If you want to serialize something else then convert it into a basic type with e.g. `values()` or `values_list()` and then use the normal JSON mechanism to serialize that.

Comment: Thank you. I changed to below and it worked:                        for current_village in villages:
    persons = Person.objects.all().filter(address=current_village)
    for p in persons:
        personsList.append(p.id)  
personsListQset = Person.objects.filter(pk__in=personsList)
json_persons = serializers.serialize("json", personsListQset)